# How can I remove table rows with specific id's?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried different solutions now, but I'm not able to remove the correct rows.
*Note: In HTML5 it is valid to use numbers in ID.*

html

```
<table>
  <tr id="2"></tr>
  <tr id="5"></tr>
  <tr id="7"></tr>
  <tr id="9"></tr>
</table>
```

js

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = '7';
arr[1] = '9';

for(var row_id in arr) {
  $('table tr[id='+row_id+']').remove();
}
```

The result is always the same - some of my top rows are removed, not the bottom two.
What am I missing in this code?

**Update:** Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6PkMK/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you're using the `key` instead of `array[key]`. Let me do a quick demo...

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var i in array)
{
    console.log(i); //0, 1, 2
    console.log(array[i]); //"a", "b", "c"
}
```

You get the picture, right? The second problem is that you're, I think, using the selector variable in a wrong way. In Jquery, when you want to select an element with and id, you do it like this: `$(#id)`, not the way you're doing it.

Try this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = '7';
arr[1] = '9';

for(var row_id = 0; row_id < arr.length; row_id ++) { //The proper way to iterate
  $('#' + arr[row_id]).remove();
}
```

Again, if this is false, please let me know in the comments and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: As @am not i am says, numeric ids are wrong but this should work if you said `$("#row" + arr[row_id])...`. +1 because it should be quicker than the selector in the original answer.

Comment: @Bane   why would yours be only one correct when my ID only selectpr was posted before yors

Comment: @charlietfl: Yours was initially incorrect. You updated it after others posted the `arr[row_id]` solution *(and so did @dotoree)*.

Comment: I don't remember your answer being correct... I guess it is now. My comment was 15mins ago, seems like you've improved your answer since then. Doesn't really matter though...

Comment: @Bane - Thanks. I'm dynamically adding id's to the array, that's way I'm using `array[key]` method. As for the `for loop` - you are right. I'm just getting tired after 12h of coding :)

Answer (score 3):

I've got it to work - http://jsfiddle.net/fbjut/.

Note that you really shouldn't use numeric ids, you should start them with 'row' or something (preferably something more descriptive!).

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = '7';
arr[1] = '9';

for(var row_id in arr) {
  $('table tr[id='+arr[row_id]+']').remove();
}
​
```

Comment: You should post answers here, not just on a different site.

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking that taking the askers code, modifying it so that it works, linking to it and giving advice at the same time counted as an answer (end of sarcasm - it's not so much that I think this, it's more that **know** this is the case....).

Comment: Don't be rude. Questions and answers on StackOverflow are meant to be a resource for future readers. In order for your answer to be assured of being available in the future, it should be posted here, with offsite links being supplementary.

Comment: Sorry, just had a migraine all day and getting sick of it... I just get easily agitated when people tell me what to / not to post, how to post etc when I see some far worse answers on other posts. I especially get agitated (by anything) when my heads banging. Other answers have the solution, in parts, I just put them all together in one jsfiddle and was also the first person to post a jsfiddle.

Comment: So sweat bro. +1 to ease the pain a bit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['7','9'];

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  $('#'+arr[i]).remove();
}
```

## *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ihucuk/edit#javascript,html,live)*

---

```
/*
var arr = [];
arr[0] = '7';
arr[1] = '9';
*/
var arr = ['7','9'];

for(var row_id in arr) {
  $('#'+arr[row_id]).remove();
}
```

## *[demo2 jsBin](http://jsbin.com/amoyah/2/edit)*

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
$('table tr#'+arr[row_id]).remove();
```

Comment: This won't offer any improvement over using an *attribute-equals* selector.

Comment: @Steven, did you try my solution? Did it work? I'm also new to Jquery so I'd like feedback. :)

Comment: @Bane - That was is. I had to use `arr[row_id]`. Want to post that as an answer so I can marked this as solved?